# Troubleshooting user input for API scraping program

Tags: javascript, p5.js

This program is supposed to output lyrics from a given API. This works when the song and artist are manually set at variables before pressing the submit button. However, I realize that it cannot work when taking user input for song because the JSON load is inside setup, which is loaded before the input is even given. How would I go about fixing this? I already tried to create another function for loadJSON, but it still was not working.

The expected output should be when you press submit, the user's song (I will deal with artist input later) lyrics should be produced. Thank you!

```
var search, button, question, input;
var artist = 'One%20Direction/';
var song = 'Taken';
var url_root = 'http://lyric-api.herokuapp.com/api/find/'

function setup() {
  noCanvas();

  input = createInput ();
  input.position (20, 50);

  button = createButton ("Submit");
  button.position(input.x + input.width, 50);
  button.mousePressed(goSearch);

  var url = url_root + artist + song;
  loadJSON (url, gotData);

  question = createElement ('h2', 'Search a song:');
  question.position(20, 5);

}

function gotData(data) {
  search = data;
}

function goSearch() {
    var thing = search.lyric
    var result = createP(thing);
    result.position (20, 60);
}
```

Comment: your not showing the code for loadJson, and its not clear what your asking, perhaps add some more detail

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following provides what you're after. In summary:

- Addition of `input.value()` to get user's input value
- Minor refactoring of functions

```js
var search, button, question, input;
var artist = 'One%20Direction/';
var url_root = 'http://lyric-api.herokuapp.com/api/find/'

// Page setup
function setup() {
  noCanvas();

  input = createInput ();
  input.position (20, 50);

  button = createButton ("Submit");
  button.position(input.x + input.width, 50);
  button.mousePressed(goSearch);

  question = createElement ('h2', 'Search a song:');
  question.position(20, 5);
}

// When data is returned, lets display it
function gotData(data) {
  search = data;
  var thing = search.lyric
  var result = createP(thing);
  result.position (20, 60);
}

// Perform request when user submits search term
function goSearch() {
  var song = input.value(); // Get the form field's input value
  var url = url_root + artist + song;
  loadJSON (url, gotData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
```